# Read inside node value of Xml using Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I want to read node values of xml in sql, my xml look like this

[image]

I just want to read value of order node that is 'Order 1'
and my code is

```
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc
SELECT * FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/ROOT/Customer/Order',0)
WITH (
    [Order]  varchar(100)
    );
```

Comment: Check this post, it might help you https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/177532/how-does-this-derived-table-with-cross-apply-work/177536#177536

Answer (score 7):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test(data xml);
> insert into test values
> ('
> <ROOT>
>   <Customer>
>     <Order>Order 1</Order>
>   </Customer>
>   <Customer>
>     <Order>Order 2</Order>
>   </Customer>
> </ROOT>');
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 1 rows affected
> ```

If you need first `<Order>` element of your XML data you can use the next sentence.

> ```
> SELECT data.value('(ROOT/Customer/Order)[1]', 'varchar(100)')
> FROM   test;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name) |
> | :--------------- |
> | Order 1          |
> ```

If you need to select all `<Order>` elements you can use a CROSS APPLY solution with .nodes()

> ```
> SELECT T2.lin.value('(Order)[1]', 'varchar(100)')
> FROM   test
> CROSS APPLY data.nodes('/ROOT/Customer') as T2(lin)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name) |
> | :--------------- |
> | Order 1          |
> | Order 2          |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=0b774f0d5e6162ea638890ae661d39fb)*